# How to handle half-and-half questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

What is the best way to handle half-and-half questions?

For example, part of this question belongs on SuperUser and part belongs here:

[Retroactively download a history of all URLs I have visited in Chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/looking-for-a-way-to-retroactively-download-a-history-of-all-urls-i-have-visited)

Comment: Precision: The asker first asks for an add-on, then also ask if the feature is available by default ("Google might retain [...]") or not.